# Can't install or uninstall Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[image]

"Remove" gives an error: "Sorry something went wrong". "Retry": "Catalog has not been loaded". So I can't install or remove it. View problems shows "Couldn't download Microsoft.VisualStudio.Devenv.Config". I tried steps from http://rion.io/2017/02/17/resolving-installation-issues-with-visual-studio-2017/, but didn't help- as I reinstalled the VS installer, this still show's up. How can I wipe it out?

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the "Add or remove programs" window instead of through the installer? (Windows key and then start typing that)

Comment: Now on retry it shows: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Yes I removed it from Add/remove programs and it's not showing up there.

Comment: It's clear that VS2017 is wiped, but some stupid registry is keeping it alive in the installer :(

Comment: I have just installed VS 2022 Community Edition and the option to remove VS 2017 (Community) became available. I ran it and the reference to VS 2017 disappeared. Maybe MS developed a fix to clean up VS 2017  and packaged in VS 2022.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by cleaning windows register.

When I pressed remove, it showed uninstall path, something 'D:\xx\VS' that did not exist any more.

I opened windows Registry editor, selected top node. Then in system menu I chose Edit/Find.. and pasted the path 'D:\xx\VS' and removed every Key that contained this path. After that I reinstalled VS installer and everything worked fine.

*P.S messing with registers is dangerous so do consider the risks*